# How to convert ppt to images in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, openoffice.org, powerpoint

I'm using Ruby for displaying the contents of powerpoint files in a webpage. I've found solutions using the win32ole but I'm in the linux environment and it doesn't work. I think the application could trigger a **openoffice** command for conversion.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using [Docsplit](http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/).

Install the gem, and then you can do something like:

```
Docsplit.extract_images(filename, :size => '920x', :format => [:png])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Rjb](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/) and [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to export your powerpoint to flash (or [any other format](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter/guide/supportedformats)).

Here is a pice of code to do it :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rjb'

classpath = nil

Rjb::load( classpath, ['-Djava.awt.headless=true'] )

jFile = Rjb::import( 'java.io.File' )
jSocketOpenOfficeConnection = Rjb::import( 'com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.SocketOpenOfficeConnection' )
jOpenOfficeDocumentConverter = Rjb::import( 'com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter' )

input = jFile.new( "your-doc.ppt" )
output = jFile.new( "your-doc.swf" )

# connect to an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100
connection = jSocketOpenOfficeConnection.new( 8100 )
connection.connect()

# convert
converter = jOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.new( connection )
converter.convert( input, output )

# close the connection
connection.disconnect()
```

You need to start an OOo.org server :

```
soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard
```

And to add `jodconverter-cli-X.X.X.jar` to your CLASSPATH