# How convert powerpoint presentation in serverside to png

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert powerpoit presentation to png or jpg files. Can i do this in my serverside with ruby and ruby on rails. Or how can i do that like slideshare.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned SlideShare uses Adobe Flash. Would you mind elaborating your question a bit?

Comment: How i can show powerpoint presentations in my service?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327441/how-to-convert-ppt-to-images-in-ruby

Yes - it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is super-complicated (involves either reverse-engineering the various Microsoft PowerPoint formats, and re-rendering them as images, or else having a copy of PowerPoint on a server and writing code that will open files within it and screen capture them), and isn't something you're going to be able to do within Ruby on Rails.

Your best bet is to either 1) look into using SlideShare, or a similar service, via APIs and then embedding them within your side or 2) let people upload powerpoint files, and then if others want to view them, they have to download them again and re-open them within the application.

Or alternatively don't let people upload powerpoint files at all - instead get them to export their presentations as images or a PDF (which many browsers can view nowadays).