# Rails image documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

Are there methods in using rails to convert document files into image in order to display them as jpg or png. Perhaps there is a gem that can handle this

Comment: Can you be more specific about "document files"? A Word document is vastly different from a PDF file or a QuarkExpress document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some common ones:

- [RMagick (probably most advanced one](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/)
- [ImageScience](https://github.com/seattlerb/image_science)
- [MiniMagick](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick)

PS: you can convert PDFs to JPG to using RMagick :)

Edit: Converting MS Office Documents to images can be done using OpenOffice - here are two solutions:

- [JODConverter (See second answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327441/how-to-convert-ppt-to-images-in-ruby)
- Convert to PDF (using CUPS-PDF printer driver) like:

`openoffice.org2.4 -norestore -nofirststartwizard -nologo -headless -pt Cups-PDF sample.ppt`

and then you can convert the PDF to an image.

Comment: where can i go to find how to modify .doc and .odt

Comment: maybe theres a way to convert those to .pdf in rails?

Comment: JODConverter (See second answer) -- is an excellent solution. (but im not sure how would you implement the line  'openoffice.org2.4 -norestore -nofirststartwizard -nologo -headless -pt Cups-PDF sample.ppt' in a rails app, maybe i should just learn about CUPS-PDF) you got an up one from me

Comment: you can spawn a child process - call openoffice on command line an print the document to a pdf file. you should do this in a background job by the way (google for "rails resque github" - its a nice tool for backgroundjobs). I'd go for the JODConverter instead of the command line solution.